# Loading message or spinner icon before JSON loads in the same file as angular module and controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-scope, smarty

I am trying to figure out a way to not use $http.get() or $resource to load my JSON data from a separate file or URL since I can load my JSON data using a smarty code like $scope.products = {$data};  I want to load a spinner icon or a "loading" msg before my JSON data loads since the curly braces from angular code are ugly to display.  Here is my code below and any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var app= angular.module('mysearch', []);
app.controller('mysearchController', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.products = {$data}; 
]);
</script>

<div ng-app="mysearch">
   <div ng-controller="mysearchController">
      <div ng-repeat="item in products">
           {{item.sub_name}}
      </div>
      <p> {{item.title}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this have to work in IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `ng-cloak` directive. It prevents the document from showing unfinished AngularJS code while AngularJS is being loaded.
An example of such is :

```
  <element ng-cloak>{{yourdata}}</element>
```

**Edit 1:**

https://jsfiddle.net/ph110293/ou5e1dsv/

Use  `ng-hide` to show your spinner for the time being your angular loads and  `ng-show` to show when your scope has loaded

Comment: Please have a look at Edit 1

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!!! Thanks a lot for your help. Love the example you provided.